# Redirect Woocommerce pending and failed orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to redirect all Woocommerce failed, pending and cancelled orders to the checkot page. Currently Woocommerce is sending them to the "Pay for order" page, but instead I need them get redirected to  the checkout page where billing&shipping fields, order review table etc are shown. I tried simply copying the form-checkout.php template into the form-pay.php template, but this gae me a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not trivial task because at checkout stage we process cart data, after checkout processing cart is cleaned and order is created.

So if your want to recreate order, your need to move order data to cart, delete order and than redirect user to checkout probably. Another (and cleaner approach) is add billing&shipping fields to form-pay.php template.

Comment: I don't think this should be a problem because the pay-for-order-page still has the current cart data(in mini cart the products are still shown).